# Is there a hotel booking site which allows to filter for refundable rates?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, planning, accommodation, accommodation-search-engines

I have a trip coming up at rather short notice and while I should be covered I would like to book some backup accommodation within my price range just in case. While searching for rooms on the usual suspects, I came to notice that none offer the option to explicitly search for refundable rates only.

## Is there a hotel booking site which allows to set filters to show only refundable rates?

A [tripadvisor forum entry](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i12290-k8536650-How_to_avoid_non_refundable_hotel_quotes_while_searching-Bargain_Travel.html) suggests no, but often users here know better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

booking.com offers this option. It's called "free cancellation" and is found in the list of filters in categories "popular" and "book with ease"